# Pull a registry setting into another registry value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, virtual-machine

We are trying to pull the following registry setting in a VM:

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment
Value Name: ViewClient_Machine_Name
Value Data: "Desktop1"
```

This will give us the name of current physical device is running the VM(Desktop1).  We are then needing to write that machine name into the following key:

```
Key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client
Value Name: ClientName
Value Data: "Desktop1"
```

I've tried VBS, BAT and KIX scripting and the closest I've gotten is it adds a blank value in the key.  Help?

This is what we're working off of:

```
$strwkstn = READVALUE("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment", "ViewClient_Machine_Name")

$RC = writevalue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client","ClientName", $strwkstn,"REG_SZ")
```

When I run this, nothing happens.

This is my 1st post so sorry about messing it up, I'll get it right eventually!

Comment: Without code and error msg it's a guessing game.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `reg /?` and read the output help. Then run `reg add /?` and read again the output help. The command `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe` is the preferred executable used on command prompt or in batch file executed by `cmd.exe` to work with Windows registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to write to the `WOW6432Node` key.

If you need information to be put into the 32bit registry on a 64bit system then you can do that from a batch file with `Reg.exe` using the `/Reg:32` option:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "BO="
Set PROCESSOR_ARCHITE|Find "64">Nul&&(Set "BO=/Reg:32")
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /V "ViewClient_Machine_Name"'
) Do Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client" /V ClientName /D "%%~B" /F %BO%
```

Comment: This works perfectly on Windows 7.  Now I have to figure out why it's not running on Windows 10.  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @DavePoirier, did you run it As administrator?

Comment: Yes, I have run it as the Built-in admin and I also have full admin rights on this machine.